# Why is this function working properly in GUI-Emacs, but not in terminal Emacs?

Tags: terminal-emacs

Setup: Xubuntu 16.04, GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2

I have the following function defined.

```
(defun sudo-edit (&optional arg)
  "Edit currently visited file as root.

With a prefix ARG prompt for a file to visit.
Will also prompt for a file to visit if current
buffer is not visiting a file."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (or arg (not buffer-file-name))
      (find-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:"
                         (ido-read-file-name "Find file(as root): ")))
    (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))))
```

When I want to edit `/etc/default/grub`, and in the GUI Emacs frame I call `sudo-edit`, after typing my password, it works fine. But when I do the same with the emacsclient in terminal, it exits directly to the terminal after calling the same `sudo-edit`. And it's not responding anymore, and I cannot create another frame.

I fail to understand why Emacs is not handling this properly in terminal, and the GUI frame does it well. I couldn't find anything in the function which is related to the GUI.

Anybody that can find where this functions went wrong with the terminal Emacs?

Comment: Is the password prompt a GUI window? Or something you type in the minibuffer?

Comment: @KaushalModi In the minibuffer. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have not tried, and I cannot.. Can't sudo on work machine.